# Magento 2: address custom attribute, from Order entity to Account entity

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, customer-account, quote, custom-attributes

I've added a custom attribute to checkout:

1. added column in 'quote' and 'sales_oreder' tables
2. plugin for `Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`
3. plugin for `Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement`
4. RequireJS + `Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default` override js file
5. observer on 'sales_model_service_quote_submit_before' event

All works fine.
The field value is stored in the two tables correctly.

Then, I've added the same custom attribute to customer_address entity:

1. `$this->eavSetup->addAttribute(
   AddressMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS,
   self::CUSTOM_ATTRIBUTE_CODE,
   [])` .. etc
2. plugin for `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CustomerManagement`
3. observer (adminhtml) on 'core_layout_render_element' event

All works fine. The field value is stored linked to 'customer_address_entity' in EAV mode.

Now,
what I'm trying to do is to save the field into customer_address entity during `Checkout Onepage Success Page`, when the customer want to create his/her account.

How can I do this?